# Checking a frame with Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

i´m new using selenium for automation.

Im trying to make an automatic login for HBO Max (Practice purposes only), i can type in both fields (e-mail and password) and try if it logs in but. I want to check if it failed or not, i understand that for checking that i have to check if there appears the frame with the Fail Text but i don´t know how to switch to it´s frame for checking it.

[This is what i see when i inspect the frame, but i cant identify how to switch to it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQCwf.png)
(Ignore spanish texts, i got it in english on my Linux PC)

This is what i tried with many differents names (Im not sure they were names)

`error=driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "")`

Well, the problem is that i don´t know how to switch to it because there´s no id or name i searched for answers but i didn´t understand the xpath, css selector, etc.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look for this `div` container appearing when wrong credentials are inserted

[image]

This element can be uniquely locaoted by this CSS Selector: `[aria-label*='Error']`
Or with Python Selenium code:

```py
if driver.driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"[aria-label*='Error']"):
    print("Wrong credentials inserted")
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i discovered that it can be achieved using XPATH too, i used a longer code for it but it works too. I appreciate your help too much too

Comment: Right. Every css selector can be done with xpath. But not the opposite.